# How to make google maps links for Geo Points?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, point, topology

I have a question guys.
I can't make google links for geo points.I don't know why that code is not working.

for example I have that point below:
30.152169 41.070933

I can't see this location on Google Maps when I tryed like below.Could you please help me ?

```
public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry? GeoItem { get; set; }
 public string? GoogleMapsLink {get;set;}
 public void Links()
{
if(this.GeoItem !=null)
{
string x = this.GeoItem.Coordinate.X.ToString();
string y = this.GeoItem.Coordinate.Y.ToString();
string googleUrl = $"https://www.google.com/maps/@{x},{y},17.5z";
this.GoogleMapsLink=googleUrl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed above problem.

1. Google Maps can approve the value with '.' not ','.
   Example 30,15464 41,21516; this was the mistaken one.
2. The second one is URL. You can see the URL below.

   ```
   public void Links()
    {
      if (this.GeoItem != null && this.GeoItem.IsValid)
       {
         double x = this.GeoItem.Coordinate.X;
         double y = this.GeoItem.Coordinate.Y;
         string googleUrl = $@"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={y}%2C{x}";
         googleUrl = googleUrl.Replace(',', '.');
         this.GoogleMapsLink = googleUrl;
       }
    }
   ```